# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1604438222] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-jpa

I have a standalone app that is Up and getting below error when calling "http://localhost:8080/user/person/1604438222".(trying to get person id details from db)

2019-03-01 11:23:34.296 ERROR 52000 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [1604438222] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1604438222] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [1604438222] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]

1. Controller class :

   ```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/user")
   public class UserController {


       @Autowired
       PersonRepository personRepository; 

        @GetMapping("/person/{prsId}")
        public Person getPerson(@PathVariable Long prsId) {
             return personRepository.findByPrsId(prsId);
        }
   }
   ```
2. Repository :

   ```
   @Repository
   public interface PersonRepository extends  CrudRepository<Person, Long>
   {
       Person findByPrsId(Long Id);

   }
   ```
3. POJO

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "Person")
   public class Person {

       @Column(name = "Prs_Id")
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
       private Integer prsId;

       @Column(name = "P_Email_Internet_Addr", nullable = true, length = 255)
       private String email;


       protected Person() {
       }


       public Integer getPrsId() {
           return prsId;
       }

       public void setPrsId(Integer prsId) {
           this.prsId = prsId;
       }

       public String getEmail() {
           return email;
       }

       public void setEmail(String email) {
           this.email = email;
       }


       @Override
           public String toString() {
                   return "User [prsId=" + prsId + ", email=" + email 
                    + "]";
           }
       }
   ```

Comment: "*I have a standalone app that is Up and getting below error when calling ....*" - That's unfortunate. What's your question?

Comment: You define the PrsId as an Integer but use a Long to try and find it. 2304438636 is also larger than the Max signed Integer value.

Answer (score 2):

`2,147,483,647` is the value for `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

`2,304,438,636` is too big to be contained in an `Integer` variable

Use `Long` instead for your ids in general. Or even better, the primitive `long` since your IDs should ideally never be `null`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Integer` in POJO and `Long` in Repository and Controller. Change either all of them to use `Integer` or `Long`.